# How to find all Emacs commands whose behavior changes with a prefix arg (`C-u`)

Tags: emacs, doc, apropos

I came across this while reading documentation for `dired-mode`:

> **`C-u s SWITCHES <RET>`** lets you specify a new value for
>   `dired-listing-switches`.

How I can  find all Emacs commands whose behavior is different when you use a prefix argument (`C-u`)?

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have let you know that `C-u` *provides a prefix argument to the key sequence that follows it*. And they have pointed you to the doc (manual) and additional info about prefix arguments.

The other parts of your question are how to know which commands are affected by a prefix argument, and how does a prefix argument affect each such command.

1. There is no way to know which commands are affected by a prefix arg. In fact all commands are, in principle, but many do nothing different whether you use a prefix arg or not.
2. Because each command that takes advantage of a prefix argument can interpret it differently, use **`C-h f`** for *that command* name or **`C-h k`** for the key sequence that invokes. *The help shown will tell you how a prefix argument controls the command behavior.*

---

**Updated to respond to @aartist's suggestion to have Emacs check all command definitions**

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can easily find all commands currently defined whose doc strings mention "**prefix arg**".

One way to do this with Icicles is to use command **`icicle-fundoc`**.

- In this case, the functions whose doc you want to match are *commands*, so you use **`C-$`** during completion to filter out non-interactive functions.
- You want to match `prefix arg` anywhere, on any line, of a doc string, so you can simplify the regexp you use for matching, by converting **`.`** in your minibuffer input to match any character, including newline. You do this with **`C-M-.`** (a toggle between normal dot and any-char dot).
- The minibuffer input for `icicle-fundoc` is a [multi-completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Completions) with two parts (two patterns):

  - The first pattern matches the function name.
  - The second pattern matches the doc string for the function.
- In this case you want to match all function names, so you can provide an empty first pattern.
- You separate the two patterns using **`C-M-j`**.

So this is what you do:

**`M-x icicle-fundoc`** to invoke the command

**`C-$`** to filter out non-command functions

**`C-M-.`** to toggle **`.`** so that it matches any character, *including newline*

**`C-M-j`** to skip over the function-name pattern (to match all function names)

**`.*prefix arg`** to match the string `prefix arg` anywhere, on any doc string line

(To catch also doc strings where `prefix` is at the end of one line and `arg` is at the beginning of the next, you can instead use **`.*prefix[[:space:]]+arg`**.)

**`S-TAB`** to show the matches in buffer `*Completions*` (`S-TAB` does [apropos completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Apropos_Completions))

(Pretty much every doc string that mentions `C-u` mentions also `prefix arg`, but if you want to be sure to find those that might not, you can [widen the set of matches](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Regressive_Completion) by using **`M-+`** and typing `C-u` (followed by `RET`).)

[image]

You can further filter the set of matches by providing more patterns that the current set of candidates must match. This is [progressive completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion).  For example, if you wanted to see only the commands whose doc mentions the `prefix arg` or `C-u` and also the word `frame`, you would use **`S-SPC frame`**.

[image]

Comment: May be we can parse  definitions of all commands to find out if it does something different whether you use a prefix arg or not.  There could be a 'emacsy' way.

Answer (score 2):

Search the Lisp code for obvious signs, e.g.,
(defun ... "... prefix arg ..." (interactive "N") ...
where interactive code letters N, p, P and Z all refer to the **current-prefix-arg** variable, likewise search the C code for **Vcurrent_prefix_arg** but impossible in the general case, e.g.,

```
(symbol-value (intern (mapconcat #'symbol-name (reverse '(arg prefix current)) "-")))
(symbol-value (intern (reverse "gra-xiferp-tnerruc")))
```

both calculate the **current-prefix-arg** value but would elude most searches.
The **load-path** variable lists the directories of **.el* files; the *src* directory, if included in your distribution, has the **.c* files.
In a fresh Emacs with not much loaded, an in-memory search by `M-x commands-with-prefix-arg Ret` reports `Emacs version 26.0.90: 3422 with, 7921 without.`

```
(defun commands-with-prefix-arg ()
  "List of two lists: loaded lisp commands that refer to `current-prefix-arg' and those that don't appear to."
  (interactive)
  (let ((with '())
        (without '())
        (buffer (get-buffer-create "*Disassemble*"))
        (case-fold-search nil)
        (debug-on-error nil))
    (mapatoms (lambda (symbol)
                (cond ((not (commandp symbol)))
                      ((or (ignore-errors
                             (string-match "\\(^\\|\n\\)[NpPZ]" (cadr (interactive-form symbol))))
                           (ignore-errors
                             (string-match "prefix[ \t\n\f]*arg\\|universal-argument" (documentation symbol t)))
                           (ignore-errors
                             (with-current-buffer buffer
                               (erase-buffer)
                               (print (symbol-function symbol) buffer)
                               (goto-char (point-min))
                               (search-forward "\\<current-prefix-arg\\>"))))
                       (push symbol with))
                      (t
                       (push symbol without)))))
    (message "Emacs version %s: %d with, %d without."
             emacs-version
             (length with)
             (length without))
    (list with
          without)))
```

Paste this code in your `*scratch*` buffer then type the `C-j` character, i.e., Control-J.
Type `(mapcar #'print (car (commands-with-prefix-arg))) C-j`
for the first list — commands with a prefix arg.  For the others,
type `(mapcar #'print (cadr (commands-with-prefix-arg))) C-j`

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>C-u</kbd> is the ["universal prefix argument"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html) rather than an actual command.

IOW, it *modifies* the behavior of the command invoked by <kbd>s</kbd> in the way idiosyncratic to that command.

Answer (score 1):

`C-u` is bound to the `universal-argument` command that handles specification of prefix to Emacs commands.  They are available to all commands, but the command may not handle it, or change behaviour.

You can find more information in the [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrefixArgument), and [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html).